# javax.persistence.EntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()Ljavax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 4, Spring 3 and JSF 2.0 and Weblogic 10.3.6
I have the following in DAO class

```
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Request> c = cb.createQuery(Request.class);
```

When I run my application I am getting the following exception.

```
javax.persistence.EntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()Ljavax/persistence/criteria
/CriteriaBuilder;

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
javax.persistence.EntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()Ljavax/persistence/criteria
    /CriteriaBuilder;
    at net.test.request.dao.RequestDAOImpl.getRequest(RequestDAOImpl.java:51)
```

I did not use JPA1 jars, however I am still getting this exception. Not able to figure how to get rid of this exception. Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

pom.xml

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSF library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Primefaces library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>flick</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Oracle Java Connector library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4j library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- source output directory -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/metamodel</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `EntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder` is a part of JPA 2 (which is part of Java EE 6), which is not provided and/or turned on by default in WebLogic 10.

Here is a link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13720/using_toplink.htm which provides instructions that may fix your problem.  If not, you'll need to start googling "weblogic 10 jpa 2" and see if you can find a solution that works for you.

If none of these solutions work, your last resort will be to redesign your application to only use JPA 1 methods.  To use JPA 1 you must limit yourself to the classes and interfaces defined here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html

[update]

Or - since you are using Hibernate anyways, don't rely so much on JPA classes.  Use hibernate specific classes instead.  Hibernate has had criteria since 3.x.  Instead of an EntityManager you create a Hibernate session factory.  Then you can do:

```
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

...

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
```

Your code is now locked into using Hibernate as your persistence provider.  In my case we always use Hibernate so it's not a real problem.  This is a question you have to decide for yourself.  If your application can tolerate being locked into Hibernate, this should give you the functionality you need while still running on WebLogic.

Comment: I have question, without EntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder I have deployed a small application to Weblogic and it worked. So would like to know how that got worked?

Comment: @Polppan It works now because you are using JPA 1.  Click the javadoc link in the answer to see which classes and methods are in JPA 1. Note that EntityManager in the link does NOT have getCriteriaBuilder. If you can limit yourself to these methods, your software will run on WebLogic.

Comment: I have addded `@rem Enable JPA 2.0 functionality on WebLogic Server
set PRE_CLASSPATH=%BEA_HOME%\modules\javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_1-0-2.jar;%BEA_HOME%\modules\com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar` in `commEnv.cmd`, however problem still persists.

Comment: What is the alternative to this in JPA1 `CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Employee> c = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);`

Comment: Before I move to Hibernate API, I have one more question, in my \wls1036_dev\modules folder I have `javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_1-0-2.jar` and `javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0.jar`. If I use `javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0.jar`, then I am getting null pointer exception at   `CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();`. If I use `javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_1-0-2.jar` then orginal problem still persists. Any idea what could be the reason for this?

Comment: @Polppan Sorry no idea.  I'm a Tomcat guy and have never used WebLogic.  You are getting too deep for me :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out. Much appreciated for your help. I do have a problem if I would want to switch to Hibernate API. I am following [this](http://hrycan-blog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/prime/src/main/java/com/hrycan/prime/dao/impl/EmployeeDaoJPA.java) article for lazy loading for primefaces datatable. In this I am trying to implement `findEmployees(EmployeeQueryData data)`. Problem is here it using JPA2 I guess. So not sure how could I get equivalent API for Hibernate.