# How to keep Criteria queries in Hibernate 5.2+?

Tags: java, hibernate

I try to use hibernate 5.2+ with Criteria. 
I found 2 ways to create Criteria queries.

1. This code is deprecated: `sessionFactory.openSession().createCriteria(MyClass.class);`
2. This code throws a NoSuchMethodError: `sessionFactory.openSession().getCriteriaBuilder();`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getCriteriaBuilder()Ljavax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder;
```

The other non-ciriteria `session.update()` or `session.save()` function are working perfectly.

My maven dependecies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

How can I use correctly my Criteria queries?

[UPDATE]

I use Wildfly 10, and hibernate.cfg.xml config files.

Comment: since scope is provided, can you check whether in runtime it has same version or not.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980546/javax-persistence-entitymanager-getcriteriabuilderljavax-persistence-criteria). Also have you looked at the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria)?

Comment: Thank you! I saw it, but i use Wildfly 10, and the other solution here is the deprecated version. Yes I have looked the documentation, but I have hibernate.cfg.xml and if I know right it is not possible to create `EntityManager` from that configuration file.

Comment: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1917